# How to find the name with spaces using java.rmi.Naming.lookup()?

Tags: java, rmi, naming

I register a RMI Object using these codes on the Server side:

```
IHello stub = (IHello)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, 20200);
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(20222);
registry.bind("A Say Hello Remote Object", stub);
```

When I get this remote Object from client:

```
IHello stub = (IHello)Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:20222/A Say Hello Remote Object");
```

This will throws an Exception:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: invalid URL STring rmi://localhost:20222/A Say Hello Remote Object.
```

On the client side, I can use `regitry.lookup("A Say Hello Remote Object")` to find this object. But why the `Naming.lookup()` method can't work?

Comment: Wild guess: the spaces need to be URL-encoded, so replace them with `%20`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Great! That works!

Comment: `+` sign can't work. It throws an Exception: `java.rmi.NotBoundException: A+Say+Hello+Remote+Object`. @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: See https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4641504

Comment: @EugenCovaci Thanks. I use jdk 1.7.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen You haven't tried it.  Spaces in a URL are encoded as `%20`, Only spaces in *arguments* are encoded as `+`. Don't post guesswork here.